# How to obtain 5-star cards?

Tags: pocket-mine

I get 2-star cards by combining 2 1-star cards. Do I get more-star cards by waiting before fusing, or will fusing only happen between two cards of the same star-rank and increase the star-rank by 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify. If you have a X star card and get a new same type 1 star card you can fuse them to get a X+1 star card. So to get a 5 start card you would need a 4 star card and a 1 star card.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that fact (as can be read in the question).

Comment: @Mathias711 just want to point out that the two answers seem to disagree, so if you determine this one is correct you might want to move your checkmark.

Comment: @gatherer818 You are right. I didn't notice it, so I removed the check on the other answer and kept on playing until I could fuse some cards. It turned out this answer is true.

Answer (score 2):

you always have to combine to n-1 star cards, to get a n-star card.

Comment: This is not true. I fused a 1-star and 2-star into a 3-star card